# Dealing with conspiracy theorists

Tags: discussion

A couple of questions I've answered have resulted in comment threads with people I'd loosely call "conspiracy theorists". They have opinions that are non-mainstream, with a general theme that "the government/media are lying to us". The views are not crazy - we're not talking about George Bush being a reptile or anything like that. However, I feel this tends to lead discussion in a direction that I don't find constructive.

Here are some examples (look in the comments):

- [When a stock market crashes, how does money just disappear?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/13312/when-a-stock-market-crashes-how-does-money-just-disappear/13317#13317)
- [Is there collaboration between cyber criminals and banks?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/13651/is-there-collaboration-between-cyber-criminals-and-banks/13679#13679)

Have you any suggestions for dealing with this? Maybe simply ignoring comments that go in that direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes simply ignore comments that go in that direction. I see no other way, and moreover, they have nothing to do with the Economics discipline in any case.